# What's the correct format of private_key when using it as an environment variable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam, google-auth-library-nodejs

I am trying to use `private_key` for some GCP service nodejs client libraries, e.g. `@google-cloud/pubsub`, `@google-cloud/trace-agent`

I got `private_key` from service account credential json file like this:

[image]

I am trying to use it as an environment variable for cloud function.

`.env.yaml`:

[image]

And use it like this:

```
// ...

  credentials: {
        private_key: envs.private_key,
        client_email: envs.client_email
  },
  projectId: envs.X_GOOGLE_GCLOUD_PROJECT
```

But got an error:

> Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

I check stackdriver logs, here is the `private_key` environment variable I got:

[image]

My guess is the format of `private_key` is not correct. It's probably caused by the newline symbol `\n`.  So, what's the correct format when using `private_key` like this?

Comment: @Rob I think it depends on the situation, not NEVER. My question hit this situation. Because the chars of the secret key are too many so that if I use text instead of posting an image. It will reduce readability!! I don't agree with you downvote and close my question!! Don't see the picture in question and close the question

Comment: I already gave you a reason and a link to the rules. Your images are not copyable to help duplicate your problem. They are not searchable and are barely readable if readable at all.

Comment: As I said, it's not code, I know it shouldn't post an image for code. But I post image for a secret key, it's not worth to copy and search.

Comment: Is it any error messages or output of data? If you know you shouldn't do it, then don't do it.

Comment: Can't you see the `Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`?

Comment: The private key by itself is not enough for Google services if used for authentication. Take the entire JSON key material, base64 and stuff that into your environment variable. If you are just using the private key for other purposes, base64 that part. When you decode, you will have an exact duplicate of the original key text.

Comment: I neither a fan of nor an expert in the fickle beast called YAML but I don't think `\n` in YAML means "newline" unless the string is double-quoted -- it just means the two characters '\' and 'n' which would explain why that backslash is being escaped with another one in the logs -- because it's a literal backslash.  Consider quoting the value... `private_key: "-----BEGIN..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the key in the .env.yaml file is not a good idea. Indeed, you will be able to commit it to git, maybe in a public repo, and you will set it in plain text as environment variable of your function.

It will be better if you set the file in a bucket, and load it in the runtime. BTW you will keep no secret in the project files.

Another solution is to encrypt with kms the key and decrypt it at runtime. This time you still have the secret in your project files, but encrypted.

But, what do you need another service account? This one on the function is not enough?

Comment: I know that. It's ok. It's only for testing.

Comment: So, what you don't set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL param to your environment which point to your key file? By the way the behavior will be the same as using the function service account

Comment: I know `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL` stuff too, but it's not my question asks.

Comment: Sure, it was just too be sure that you are on the right way for production grade app.

Answer (score 0):

```
GCLOUD_KEY='{"private_key_id":"XXX", "private_key":"YYY",
             "client_email":"ZZZ@ZZZ.COM", "client_id":"ABC123",
             "type":"service_account"}'
```